# Play Framework 2.8.x MySQL Connection Issue

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, sbt, hikaricp

**application.conf**

```
application.secret = <secret code>
application.session.maxAge = 5m
application.session.secure = true
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer = 512M
application.langs = "en"

db.default.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db_name>"
db.default.username = "username"
db.default.password = "password"

db.default.logSql=true

play.evolutions.enabled=false

ebean.default = ["package.to.models.*"]
```

I unable to find what's wrong with this issue i refer play framework official [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/)

seems it says unable to inject dependancies

```
Error injecting constructor, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 29996ms
```

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
  .settings(
    name := """project_name""",
    organization := "com.package",
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.1",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        guice,
        jdbc,
        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.19",
        "it.innove" % "play2-pdf" % "1.10.0",
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-feature",
      "-deprecation",
      "-Xfatal-warnings"
    )
  )
```

Comment: As the end of message says `Connection is not available...` this highly likely caused by MySql un-availabilty. Please, check that MySql up and running and available by url specified in `db.default.url` config and credentials are correct.

Comment: Yes everything is fine, server is running and connection param also correct, but it is show hikaricp timeout

Comment: Well, did you try plugging in the actual DB name instead of <db_name>?

Comment: yes of course
and username password too

Answer (score 0):

Problem is it is missing JAXB-API dependancies it is required by Eban ORM

update the **build.sbt** file as bellow

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
  .settings(
    name := """project_name""",
    organization := "com.package",
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.1",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        guice,
        jdbc,
        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.19",
        "it.innove" % "play2-pdf" % "1.10.0",
        // To provide an implementation of JAXB-API, which is required by Ebean.
        "javax.xml.bind" % "jaxb-api" % "2.3.1",
        "javax.activation" % "activation" % "1.1.1",
        "org.glassfish.jaxb" % "jaxb-runtime" % "2.3.2",
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-feature",
      "-deprecation",
      "-Xfatal-warnings"
    )
  )
```